# What is the difference between texlive2016-20160523, texlive2016, and TexLive *.iso files

Tags: texlive, texlive-2016

They all seem to be the same size (3G). What's the difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `texlive-20160523` would refer to the official, *first* release of TeX Live 2016 that was slated for June 6th, 2016. The date of May 23rd, 2016 probably references when inclusions into TeX Live 2016 was halted/[frozen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55459/5764).
- `texlive2016` may refer to a *current* bundling of the entire TeX Live 2016 distribution. This may differ from the above as packages may have been updated since the official release.
- [`texlive.iso`](https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-iso.html) provides an packages version of `texlive-20160523` specific for burning to a disc.

You can download either one of the above and install it. Once fully installed, you can push an [update](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/5764) to make sure you have the latest and greatest.

Comment: On CTAN (`http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/texlive/Images`) two of these are links that point to the third. Thus they are effectively the same.